# KVM inside Docker inside Hyper-V

Tags: docker, hyper-v, linux-kvm

On top there is a VM created with Hyper-V. Inside this VM, we run a Docker container. Inside this Docker container, we run KVM. When trying to create a new Windows VM using this KVM, these errors are displayed:

```
> root@0a25149f706c:/var/log/libvirt# cat libvirtd.log 2019-11-05
> 10:54:56.137+0000: 5201: info : libvirt version: 4.0.0, package:
> 1ubuntu8.13 (Christian Ehrhardt <christian.ehrhardt@canonical.com>
> Wed, 21 Aug 2019 11:08:                           29 +0200) 2019-11-05
> 10:54:56.137+0000: 5201: info : hostname: 634d767f325e 2019-11-05
> 10:54:56.137+0000: 5201: error : virDBusGetSystemBus:109 : internal
> error: Unable to get DBus system bus connection: Failed to connect to
> socket /var/run/d                           bus/system_bus_socket: No
> such file or directory 2019-11-05 10:54:56.137+0000: 5201: error :
> dnsmasqCapsRefreshInternal:741 : Cannot check dnsmasq binary
> /usr/sbin/dnsmasq: No such file or directory 2019-11-05
> 10:54:56.210+0000: 5201: error : virFirewallValidateBackend:193 :
> direct firewall backend requested, but /sbin/ebtables is not
> available: No such file or d                           irectory
> 2019-11-05 10:54:56.210+0000: 5201: error : virFirewallApply:916 :
> internal error: Failed to initialize a valid firewall backend
> 2019-11-05 10:54:57.768+0000: 5201: error : virSysinfoReadX86:1032 :
> internal error: Failed to find path for dmidecode binary 2019-11-05
> 10:54:57.768+0000: 5201: error : virSysinfoReadX86:1032 : internal
> error: Failed to find path for dmidecode binary 2019-11-05
> 10:54:57.780+0000: 5201: error : virNodeSuspendSupportsTarget:336 :
> internal error: Cannot probe for supported suspend types 2019-11-05
> 10:54:57.780+0000: 5201: warning : virQEMUCapsInit:1224 : Failed to
> get host power management capabilities 2019-11-05 10:54:59.525+0000:
> 5201: error : virNodeSuspendSupportsTarget:336 : internal error:
> Cannot probe for supported suspend types 2019-11-05 10:54:59.525+0000:
> 5201: warning : umlCapsInit:76 : Failed to get host power management
> capabilities 2019-11-05 10:54:59.525+0000: 5201: error :
> virNetDevBridgeCreate:484 : error creating bridge interface virbr0:
> Operation not permitted 2019-11-08 13:19:45.472+0000: 59: info :
> libvirt version: 4.0.0, package: 1ubuntu8.13 (Christian Ehrhardt
> <christian.ehrhardt@canonical.com> Wed, 21 Aug 2019 11:08:29          
> +0200) 2019-11-08 13:19:45.472+0000: 59: info : hostname: 0a25149f706c 2019-11-08 13:19:45.472+0000: 59: error :
> dnsmasqCapsRefreshInternal:741 : Cannot check dnsmasq binary
> /usr/sbin/dnsmasq: No such file or directory 2019-11-08
> 13:19:45.476+0000: 59: error : virFirewallValidateBackend:193 : direct
> firewall backend requested, but /sbin/ebtables is not available: No
> such file or dir                           ectory 2019-11-08
> 13:19:45.476+0000: 59: error : virFirewallApply:916 : internal error:
> Failed to initialize a valid firewall backend 2019-11-08
> 13:19:45.478+0000: 59: error : virSysinfoReadX86:1032 : internal
> error: Failed to find path for dmidecode binary 2019-11-08
> 13:19:45.478+0000: 59: error : virSysinfoReadX86:1032 : internal
> error: Failed to find path for dmidecode binary 2019-11-08
> 13:19:45.490+0000: 59: error : virNodeSuspendSupportsTarget:336 :
> internal error: Cannot probe for supported suspend types 2019-11-08
> 13:19:45.490+0000: 59: warning : virQEMUCapsInit:1224 : Failed to get
> host power management capabilities 2019-11-08 13:19:48.331+0000: 59:
> error : virSysinfoReadX86:1032 : internal error: Failed to find path
> for dmidecode binary 2019-11-08 13:19:48.770+0000: 59: error :
> virNodeSuspendSupportsTarget:336 : internal error: Cannot probe for
> supported suspend types 2019-11-08 13:19:48.770+0000: 59: warning :
> virLXCDriverCapsInit:90 : Failed to get host power management
> capabilities 2019-11-08 13:19:48.772+0000: 59: error :
> virNodeSuspendSupportsTarget:336 : internal error: Cannot probe for
> supported suspend types 2019-11-08 13:19:48.772+0000: 59: warning :
> umlCapsInit:76 : Failed to get host power management capabilities
> 2019-11-08 13:19:48.774+0000: 59: error : virFirewallApply:916 :
> internal error: Failed to initialize a valid firewall backend
```

Comment: No, Hyper-V doesn't pass through the necessary hardware virtualization for KVM to work.  Also, it's completely unsupported by Microsoft.

Comment: Also worth noting that you're attempting 3rd level nested virtualization which is not recommended.